# File is not shown in the folder generated via tcl script

Tags: io, tcl, bioinformatics, protein-database, vmd

I am trying to write a file using tcl scripting (Via VMD). when I type command "dir" on tk/tcl console, it shows file name which I am trying to generate. But when I tried to open that file manually in that working directory folder, it is not even shown in it.

Here is the piece of code.

```
set fp [open "input.txt" w+]
puts $fp "test"
close $fp
```

Comment: And what does `pwd` show in the tcl/tk console?

Comment: C:/Program Files (x86)/University of Illinois/VMD same directory where my script is present.

Comment: Your script will either write a file with that name in the current directory, or will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Windows can be *deeply* tricky about what is going on with the actual folders.

If you do this in your script as well:

```
# This is quite an incantation!
exec {*}[auto_execok cmd] /c start "" [file nativename [file normalize .]]
```

then it should open an Explorer window on the actual current directory. That will let you check whether the file is actually there, and whether where you are is where you expect to be.

This should match up with what this says:

```
# Print the current working directory
puts [pwd]
# Print the names of text files in the current directory, with full names
puts [glob -directory [pwd] *.txt]
```

If it doesn't, that might point to your real problem…

Comment: Okay, i just changed the working directory and it worked for me.